# Javascript object get object using variable

Tags: javascript, object

I am attempting to use a variable to collect information from an object.  I am a php programmer and im not very good with javascript yet.

```
var priceobj= {'Youth Small':'0', 'Youth Meduim':'0', 'Youth Large':'0','Adult Small':'0','Adult Medium':'0','Adult Large':'0','Adult XL':'0','Adult XXL':'2','Adult XXXL':'3'};

var os0 = $('#os0').val(); // value will be one of the options in priceobj

var value = priceobj.os0 // this should read 0,2,3 depending on the value of os0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var value = priceobj[os0];
```

os0 isn't a key, it's a value which represents a key. The way you called it, it would have to be a key.